# Load data into file memory in firebase storage with flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I would like to know if it is possible to load data in memory from a file stored in firebase storage?
My goal is to open the file and show the data in the browser, without downloading it to the computer. Firebase is configured correctly in my project, I can upload and get URL.
I tried using the command below, but I get an error:

```
await FirebaseStorage.instance
  .ref()
  .child(TabelaIbptConsts.PATH_TABELAS)
  .child('MG.csv')
  .getData()
  .then((value) => print(value));
```

I get the error below:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 909:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 71:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1613:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 155:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 707:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 736:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 533:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1219:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37307:58                              <fn>
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:63639/dart_sdk.js:5054:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:63639/dart_sdk.js:37670:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:63639/dart_sdk.js:37666:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:63639/dart_sdk.js:37526:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:63639/dart_sdk.js:37532:13)
    at http://localhost:63639/dart_sdk.js:33303:9
```